# Semantic differences between save/write/store and read/load?

Tags: load, save, store

I never know what is the correct name for a function that writes/stores/saves something in a file. When should I use `save()` vs `store()` vs `write()` and what is the difference in meaning between those?

I guess `store`is used if I write to a database, `write`for text files and `save`for binary data, is that correct? What about XML files?

Answer (score 5):

Well, it is up to you. I personally use `saveXXX()` and `loadXXX()` for most of such code and it's quite not important how the data is saved technically (file, DB etc). From application point of view it makes no difference. Code that saves just needs data to put it in the storage, more or less persistent, and it does not really bother how it is done by the storage layer. I simply suggest to stick to one naming, basically for sake of simplicity and consistency.

Answer (score 5):

I use `load` / `save` for methods that implicitly know or infer where to get or put the data, whereas `read` and `write` methods explicitly need to be told so. I guess that in the end it's completely arbitrary, but a community consensus on when to use which word would be nice to know.

Answer (score 4):

I would say that `save` and `store` are more or less interchangeable. I prefer `save` though.

`write` I interpret as writing out the content and do nothing else, while `save` also closes the file.

Comment: Good point. `Save` usually consists of `open` (or `connect`), `write`, `close` (or `disconnect`), while `write` is, let's say, atomic.

Comment: But in a desktop application like a word processor or an image editing program, save usually does not close the file.

Comment: @kirdie it depends on the application (i.e. gimp does not lock the file, while PS does).

Comment: @KonradHöffner, true. I meant close in the file handle sense. Like, `OutputStream.write` writes data, but leaves the stream open.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion here:

```
set/get:    change/grab var value.
store:      copy/pointer value(s) to var/array.
read/write: deal with files (.txt, .json .png ...etc).
save/load:  store/grab objects/instance to var.
```